# Sticky header get stuck at the middle of the site

Tags: html, css, header, sticky

I created a header with the position set to sticky and top to 0.
But if I scroll down the page, at some point the header stop scrolling with the page.

I think it's an easy fix, but I'm just too dumb for it...

I tried to remove other elements because I thought they were intersecting with the header, but that didn't really work.

```css
header#navbar {
    grid-area: navbar;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, rgb(230, 230, 230));

    position: sticky;
    top: 0;

    z-index: 10;

    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<header id="navbar">
    <div class="navbar"></div>
</header>
```

I expected the header to be at the top of the viewport the entire time, and not disappearing at some point of scrolling.

Comment: Here are my full [CSS](https://pastebin.com/2FpYxWWn) and [HTML](https://pastebin.com/3KLdMiM5) files

Comment: Hi Squeez! Welcome to S.O.
Please provide minimum reproducible code in the question. The pastebin link will be removed in the future and is not helpful for future readers. Currently your code does not execute to anything.

Comment: Hello all, I wan't to thank all of you for your answers.
I've tried all of your answers and they were all great, but didn't work really for my code for some reason. But still, the answers will help someone some day.
I found a way to make it work by giving the header the **fixed** position instead of **sticky** and giving it a **width and height**. For sure this is not the best way to accomplish my problem, but it works for me.
But again thanks to all of you and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Hello Squeez Music and welcome to stackoverflow!

Unfortunately we can't really help you with the problem because you haven't shared enough code. What you have shared should work perfectly fine. To demonstrate I've made a snippet, and you'll see the navbar never disappears.

To get to the bottom of this, it would be a good idea to make a snippet of your own which reproduces the problem you're having. In fact, in the process of doing so you may well figure it out for yourself.

Here's what I'm talking about:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

```css
header#navbar {
        grid-area: navbar;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, rgb(230, 230, 230));

        position: sticky;
        top: 0;

        z-index: 10;

        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    }
```

```html
<header id="navbar" style="padding: 5px">
    <div class="navbar">Check out my nav bar</div>
</header>
<div style="padding: 5px">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras varius, nunc id pulvinar sagittis, enim sapien convallis ex, a egestas dui augue id ipsum. Nunc lorem neque, posuere ut neque eu, sagittis tristique massa. Suspendisse hendrerit velit augue, nec facilisis lorem finibus at. In lobortis finibus diam eget consectetur. Cras vitae dignissim est, id ornare quam. Integer convallis laoreet enim, sed consectetur tellus cursus in. Cras fermentum neque quis eleifend pretium. Vivamus maximus dui eu cursus rhoncus. Mauris bibendum venenatis quam non semper. Nam ut egestas libero. Aliquam rutrum risus at diam consequat, in viverra enim ultricies. Praesent vitae ullamcorper sapien. Quisque suscipit bibendum ex, id scelerisque metus. Sed id est sed sapien cursus sodales vitae non dui. Phasellus sit amet mauris a metus feugiat scelerisque nec non urna. Pellentesque lacinia ultricies ante, vel maximus nisl sagittis vitae.<br><br>
Aliquam aliquet sit amet erat sit amet tincidunt. Nullam et pulvinar mauris. Aenean rhoncus ut tellus in bibendum. Praesent sed consequat libero, interdum interdum lacus. Ut facilisis luctus neque ac maximus. Aenean ac maximus risus, eget vulputate tortor. Integer sed maximus odio. Fusce consectetur enim eu urna dignissim semper sit amet sed ipsum. Morbi consectetur diam sollicitudin orci ornare pellentesque. Donec nec justo ornare, tincidunt nulla ut, varius arcu. Quisque ac ipsum at nunc aliquam efficitur.<br><br>
Phasellus aliquam ornare augue nec faucibus. Etiam iaculis tincidunt feugiat. Nam auctor fringilla nunc, eu dictum odio gravida id. Donec vitae turpis ut nisl condimentum gravida. Aenean eleifend tellus arcu, non vestibulum eros cursus vel. Sed id lacinia magna. Curabitur mattis eleifend pharetra. Proin ut arcu ultricies, gravida turpis sit amet, auctor augue. Sed dictum gravida dictum.<br><br>
Suspendisse in felis mollis, condimentum nulla vel, mollis neque. Integer sagittis, sem eu lobortis ultricies, dolor tellus vestibulum lorem, sed elementum dui tortor vitae neque. Donec id massa eget enim laoreet lacinia in id arcu. Praesent consectetur dolor a nibh aliquam ullamcorper. In vehicula mollis tellus ut ornare. Quisque fringilla dignissim nisi quis tempus. Integer aliquet orci quam, vitae rutrum turpis sollicitudin ullamcorper. Pellentesque imperdiet ac orci quis tempor. Sed a lobortis odio.<br><br>
Nullam in massa id ligula pellentesque convallis. Morbi sagittis consectetur dui in mollis. Mauris a ultrices mi. Suspendisse vulputate vulputate vehicula. Curabitur sit amet sem nunc. Vestibulum vitae convallis libero. Vivamus imperdiet in tortor id suscipit.

Donec venenatis quam sagittis risus iaculis accumsan. Praesent egestas tincidunt placerat. Nulla fringilla sodales velit, vitae interdum mauris iaculis et. Donec tempor dignissim magna non ultrices. Etiam arcu ipsum, interdum in mi mattis, laoreet tincidunt magna. In eu est leo. Cras dapibus, ante sit amet viverra accumsan, dolor ipsum eleifend nibh, sit amet rhoncus enim felis a felis. Fusce quis odio lobortis, eleifend urna nec, aliquet orci. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce molestie a tellus quis fringilla. Aenean condimentum, ligula vel vulputate euismod, ipsum urna malesuada lorem, laoreet eleifend turpis felis vel mi.<br><br>
Morbi interdum, ligula ornare cursus auctor, felis sapien faucibus tellus, nec pretium eros nisi at arcu. Aliquam a neque risus. Fusce ultricies metus turpis, sed semper enim maximus tincidunt. Integer sed tortor ut orci fermentum commodo ac id lacus. Maecenas viverra neque eget ipsum semper, in finibus sapien pretium. Phasellus pretium gravida magna ut commodo. Ut vel ultrices lorem, commodo euismod dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec vestibulum malesuada metus nec pretium.<br><br>
Curabitur mattis scelerisque porta. Morbi quis viverra lacus, id imperdiet nunc. Sed facilisis, arcu quis varius vulputate, sem diam luctus nunc, non rutrum felis purus eget ex. Nam condimentum fringilla maximus. Vivamus interdum rutrum sodales. Proin fermentum lacus hendrerit pretium tempor. Mauris eleifend molestie massa a placerat. Sed in lobortis massa. Ut in tincidunt dui. Pellentesque ultrices finibus magna ac faucibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris odio ligula, luctus eget ultrices ac, pellentesque sit amet arcu. Morbi eu metus augue.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras varius, nunc id pulvinar sagittis, enim sapien convallis ex, a egestas dui augue id ipsum. Nunc lorem neque, posuere ut neque eu, sagittis tristique massa. Suspendisse hendrerit velit augue, nec facilisis lorem finibus at. In lobortis finibus diam eget consectetur. Cras vitae dignissim est, id ornare quam. Integer convallis laoreet enim, sed consectetur tellus cursus in. Cras fermentum neque quis eleifend pretium. Vivamus maximus dui eu cursus rhoncus. Mauris bibendum venenatis quam non semper. Nam ut egestas libero. Aliquam rutrum risus at diam consequat, in viverra enim ultricies. Praesent vitae ullamcorper sapien. Quisque suscipit bibendum ex, id scelerisque metus. Sed id est sed sapien cursus sodales vitae non dui. Phasellus sit amet mauris a metus feugiat scelerisque nec non urna. Pellentesque lacinia ultricies ante, vel maximus nisl sagittis vitae.<br><br>
Aliquam aliquet sit amet erat sit amet tincidunt. Nullam et pulvinar mauris. Aenean rhoncus ut tellus in bibendum. Praesent sed consequat libero, interdum interdum lacus. Ut facilisis luctus neque ac maximus. Aenean ac maximus risus, eget vulputate tortor. Integer sed maximus odio. Fusce consectetur enim eu urna dignissim semper sit amet sed ipsum. Morbi consectetur diam sollicitudin orci ornare pellentesque. Donec nec justo ornare, tincidunt nulla ut, varius arcu. Quisque ac ipsum at nunc aliquam efficitur.<br><br>
Phasellus aliquam ornare augue nec faucibus. Etiam iaculis tincidunt feugiat. Nam auctor fringilla nunc, eu dictum odio gravida id. Donec vitae turpis ut nisl condimentum gravida. Aenean eleifend tellus arcu, non vestibulum eros cursus vel. Sed id lacinia magna. Curabitur mattis eleifend pharetra. Proin ut arcu ultricies, gravida turpis sit amet, auctor augue. Sed dictum gravida dictum.<br><br>
Suspendisse in felis mollis, condimentum nulla vel, mollis neque. Integer sagittis, sem eu lobortis ultricies, dolor tellus vestibulum lorem, sed elementum dui tortor vitae neque. Donec id massa eget enim laoreet lacinia in id arcu. Praesent consectetur dolor a nibh aliquam ullamcorper. In vehicula mollis tellus ut ornare. Quisque fringilla dignissim nisi quis tempus. Integer aliquet orci quam, vitae rutrum turpis sollicitudin ullamcorper. Pellentesque imperdiet ac orci quis tempor. Sed a lobortis odio.<br><br>
Nullam in massa id ligula pellentesque convallis. Morbi sagittis consectetur dui in mollis. Mauris a ultrices mi. Suspendisse vulputate vulputate vehicula. Curabitur sit amet sem nunc. Vestibulum vitae convallis libero. Vivamus imperdiet in tortor id suscipit.<br><br>
Donec venenatis quam sagittis risus iaculis accumsan. Praesent egestas tincidunt placerat. Nulla fringilla sodales velit, vitae interdum mauris iaculis et. Donec tempor dignissim magna non ultrices. Etiam arcu ipsum, interdum in mi mattis, laoreet tincidunt magna. In eu est leo. Cras dapibus, ante sit amet viverra accumsan, dolor ipsum eleifend nibh, sit amet rhoncus enim felis a felis. Fusce quis odio lobortis, eleifend urna nec, aliquet orci. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce molestie a tellus quis fringilla. Aenean condimentum, ligula vel vulputate euismod, ipsum urna malesuada lorem, laoreet eleifend turpis felis vel mi.<br><br>
Morbi interdum, ligula ornare cursus auctor, felis sapien faucibus tellus, nec pretium eros nisi at arcu. Aliquam a neque risus. Fusce ultricies metus turpis, sed semper enim maximus tincidunt. Integer sed tortor ut orci fermentum commodo ac id lacus. Maecenas viverra neque eget ipsum semper, in finibus sapien pretium. Phasellus pretium gravida magna ut commodo. Ut vel ultrices lorem, commodo euismod dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec vestibulum malesuada metus nec pretium.<br><br>
Curabitur mattis scelerisque porta. Morbi quis viverra lacus, id imperdiet nunc. Sed facilisis, arcu quis varius vulputate, sem diam luctus nunc, non rutrum felis purus eget ex. Nam condimentum fringilla maximus. Vivamus interdum rutrum sodales. Proin fermentum lacus hendrerit pretium tempor. Mauris eleifend molestie massa a placerat. Sed in lobortis massa. Ut in tincidunt dui. Pellentesque ultrices finibus magna ac faucibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris odio ligula, luctus eget ultrices ac, pellentesque sit amet arcu. Morbi eu metus augue.</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for  your answer.
I linked my Code in my Comment.

Answer (score 0):

The header is inside the `__body`, which is the sticky container. The height of `__body` is `100%` of the `body`, which is capped at `100vh`. Since the content is longer than `100%`, the content overflows, and the actual height of the body is larger than `100vh`, hence the scroll. Since a sticky item is limited by it's container, the item is scrolled out when it reaches the center (the end of the sticky container).

Example:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

header#navbar {
  grid-area: navbar;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, rgb(230, 230, 230));
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.__body {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="__body">
  <header id="navbar">
    <div class="navbar">Navbar</div>
  </header>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mollis quis justo ut bibendum. Praesent sapien elit, pellentesque quis egestas nec, hendrerit a velit. Sed eleifend euismod nibh sit amet dignissim. Vivamus tempus neque enim, eu facilisis ligula eleifend vitae. Pellentesque accumsan vestibulum erat. Sed ut interdum nunc, vitae volutpat tellus. Vestibulum accumsan egestas finibus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque id nisl nulla.

Suspendisse ligula ligula, bibendum sit amet aliquam non, mollis in urna. Suspendisse quis dictum augue. Mauris magna est, luctus id eros vel, interdum lacinia eros. Ut eget nisl at lectus scelerisque vulputate. Etiam viverra maximus orci ut tempus. Pellentesque aliquam lectus ac nisi efficitur fringilla. Sed ut leo eget est interdum pharetra. Sed turpis ex, egestas nec vehicula sit amet, sagittis nec est. Nulla sapien mauris, mattis sit amet dui id, cursus aliquet ligula. Etiam eu orci eget ante faucibus dapibus ac sit amet ligula. Quisque eget porttitor sapien.

Donec elementum urna quam. Morbi vehicula augue et metus eleifend, at aliquet erat sodales. Mauris et tempus orci. Morbi sagittis arcu nisl, eget molestie tortor consequat et. Integer vehicula consequat risus. Vivamus eros ipsum, maximus nec orci blandit, semper commodo dui. Praesent ut dapibus justo, non elementum ligula. Aenean sagittis odio quis malesuada fermentum. Pellentesque vestibulum sem a urna cursus dapibus. Praesent ultricies sapien sed turpis dictum faucibus. Maecenas sollicitudin at justo quis accumsan. Vivamus facilisis purus felis, eu bibendum nunc tincidunt et.

Aliquam purus ex, suscipit ut nibh at, vulputate consectetur est. Sed venenatis, elit vitae consectetur iaculis, sem nunc consequat mauris, nec gravida enim orci et dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis interdum aliquam. Duis vehicula orci a pretium semper. Aliquam egestas consequat libero in interdum. Aliquam mi leo, sodales nec turpis bibendum, cursus posuere turpis. Proin vehicula magna eu libero aliquet, interdum mollis orci tincidunt. Etiam feugiat euismod magna, vel lacinia velit condimentum ac. Maecenas diam dui, aliquet non euismod at, suscipit a nulla. Aliquam elit enim, efficitur sit amet neque non, feugiat tristique enim. Ut aliquet maximus lacus, eget euismod quam. Donec vehicula ex at libero sodales, sit amet faucibus velit facilisis.

Morbi risus tortor, sollicitudin at lorem quis, convallis molestie enim. Proin efficitur libero leo, et fermentum velit eleifend in. Etiam vitae suscipit arcu. Nunc eu aliquam quam, a sollicitudin enim. Vivamus porttitor id nisl id pharetra. Sed consequat semper orci, sed iaculis arcu convallis sit amet. Donec vitae elementum nunc, ullamcorper accumsan tellus. Cras eu cursus ante.

Sed efficitur, massa a viverra scelerisque, mi magna tincidunt ipsum, ac laoreet lacus nunc quis mi. Pellentesque ut rutrum felis. Morbi euismod nisi elit, ac tristique arcu semper eget. Suspendisse orci augue, auctor quis dapibus vitae, laoreet in quam. In sagittis, odio sed suscipit mattis, risus sapien faucibus nisl, nec commodo nunc urna sit amet urna. Nulla lobortis, tellus nec auctor fermentum, lacus sapien rhoncus quam, at finibus lacus leo vel nisl. Integer eu aliquet erat. Suspendisse maximus blandit ultrices. Nunc sodales eu erat sit amet tincidunt. Nulla molestie nulla ut lectus luctus, vitae sollicitudin mi feugiat. Proin interdum elit quis lorem rhoncus ultricies. Mauris ac dui sit amet nulla lacinia venenatis in sit amet odio.
</div>
```

The solution is simple to make `__body` grow with the content.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header#navbar {
  grid-area: navbar;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, rgb(230, 230, 230));
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.__body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="__body">
  <header id="navbar">
    <div class="navbar">Navbar</div>
  </header>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mollis quis justo ut bibendum. Praesent sapien elit, pellentesque quis egestas nec, hendrerit a velit. Sed eleifend euismod nibh sit amet dignissim. Vivamus tempus neque enim, eu facilisis ligula eleifend vitae. Pellentesque accumsan vestibulum erat. Sed ut interdum nunc, vitae volutpat tellus. Vestibulum accumsan egestas finibus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque id nisl nulla.

Suspendisse ligula ligula, bibendum sit amet aliquam non, mollis in urna. Suspendisse quis dictum augue. Mauris magna est, luctus id eros vel, interdum lacinia eros. Ut eget nisl at lectus scelerisque vulputate. Etiam viverra maximus orci ut tempus. Pellentesque aliquam lectus ac nisi efficitur fringilla. Sed ut leo eget est interdum pharetra. Sed turpis ex, egestas nec vehicula sit amet, sagittis nec est. Nulla sapien mauris, mattis sit amet dui id, cursus aliquet ligula. Etiam eu orci eget ante faucibus dapibus ac sit amet ligula. Quisque eget porttitor sapien.

Donec elementum urna quam. Morbi vehicula augue et metus eleifend, at aliquet erat sodales. Mauris et tempus orci. Morbi sagittis arcu nisl, eget molestie tortor consequat et. Integer vehicula consequat risus. Vivamus eros ipsum, maximus nec orci blandit, semper commodo dui. Praesent ut dapibus justo, non elementum ligula. Aenean sagittis odio quis malesuada fermentum. Pellentesque vestibulum sem a urna cursus dapibus. Praesent ultricies sapien sed turpis dictum faucibus. Maecenas sollicitudin at justo quis accumsan. Vivamus facilisis purus felis, eu bibendum nunc tincidunt et.

Aliquam purus ex, suscipit ut nibh at, vulputate consectetur est. Sed venenatis, elit vitae consectetur iaculis, sem nunc consequat mauris, nec gravida enim orci et dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis interdum aliquam. Duis vehicula orci a pretium semper. Aliquam egestas consequat libero in interdum. Aliquam mi leo, sodales nec turpis bibendum, cursus posuere turpis. Proin vehicula magna eu libero aliquet, interdum mollis orci tincidunt. Etiam feugiat euismod magna, vel lacinia velit condimentum ac. Maecenas diam dui, aliquet non euismod at, suscipit a nulla. Aliquam elit enim, efficitur sit amet neque non, feugiat tristique enim. Ut aliquet maximus lacus, eget euismod quam. Donec vehicula ex at libero sodales, sit amet faucibus velit facilisis.

Morbi risus tortor, sollicitudin at lorem quis, convallis molestie enim. Proin efficitur libero leo, et fermentum velit eleifend in. Etiam vitae suscipit arcu. Nunc eu aliquam quam, a sollicitudin enim. Vivamus porttitor id nisl id pharetra. Sed consequat semper orci, sed iaculis arcu convallis sit amet. Donec vitae elementum nunc, ullamcorper accumsan tellus. Cras eu cursus ante.

Sed efficitur, massa a viverra scelerisque, mi magna tincidunt ipsum, ac laoreet lacus nunc quis mi. Pellentesque ut rutrum felis. Morbi euismod nisi elit, ac tristique arcu semper eget. Suspendisse orci augue, auctor quis dapibus vitae, laoreet in quam. In sagittis, odio sed suscipit mattis, risus sapien faucibus nisl, nec commodo nunc urna sit amet urna. Nulla lobortis, tellus nec auctor fermentum, lacus sapien rhoncus quam, at finibus lacus leo vel nisl. Integer eu aliquet erat. Suspendisse maximus blandit ultrices. Nunc sodales eu erat sit amet tincidunt. Nulla molestie nulla ut lectus luctus, vitae sollicitudin mi feugiat. Proin interdum elit quis lorem rhoncus ultricies. Mauris ac dui sit amet nulla lacinia venenatis in sit amet odio.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from your `grid-template-rows` in your `__body` selector. You have 170% here, your header sticks inside its parent only.
Try with:

```
    .__body {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-rows: 5.88% 17.64% 23.53% 29.11% 11.76% 11.76%;
```

You may want to try another unit than % to have something more fluid.

[edit] That's basically what Ori Drori just said :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work by giving the header the fixed position instead of sticky and giving it a width and height.